# Blender track slide issue in After Effects

Tags: camera

Camera Track question:

I have a perfect tracked footage inside Blender with an error solve of 0.3 px.

I ensured I have the correct frame rate - 30fps.

When I export the sequence (beautypass) as a whole meaning including the background footage and import to After Effect, I get a perfect track.

But I want to have individual control of shadow, beauty and ambient occlusion passes so I render them out separately in in the compositer.

Now when I import them to after effect I have sliding issues.

I re-checked the frame rate and it's correct.
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you specify the sliding issues? Maybe a screenshot highlighting the areas that don't match?

Comment: make sure that you are dealing with the correct framerate in all of the steps and timelines (30fps and 29.976 are not equal, for example). Don't render as video from blender, or in a codec that uses intrerframe compression, render as EXR multilayer if you care for quality.